# Where is the error of my implementation of "Intersection of Two Linked Lists"?

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list

I'm preparing algorithm test at Leet Code and here's the description for [N°160 Intersection of Two Linked Lists](https://leetcode.com/problems/intersection-of-two-linked-lists/):

Write a program to find the node at which the intersection of two singly linked lists begins.

For example, the following two linked lists:

```
A:          a1 → a2
                   ↘
                     c1 → c2 → c3
                   ↗            
B:     b1 → b2 → b3
```

begin to intersect at node c1.

Notes:

- If the two linked lists have no intersection at all, return `null`.
- The linked lists must retain their original structure after the function returns.
- You may assume there are no cycles anywhere in the entire linked structure.
- Your code should preferably run in O(n) time and use only O(1) memory.

---

Then I wrote a Java program to solve it. It passed 39 / 42 test cases, then failed at test 39. I've been studying for over an hour without finding the error line. Can somebody help me?

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * public class ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode next;
 *     ListNode(int x) {
 *         val = x;
 *         next = null;
 *     }
 * }
 */
public class Solution {
    public ListNode getIntersectionNode(ListNode headA, ListNode headB) {
        Stack<Integer> stackA = new Stack<>();
        Stack<Integer> stackB = new Stack<>();
        ListNode pointerA = headA;
        ListNode pointerB = headB;
        while (pointerA != null) {
            stackA.push(pointerA.val);
            pointerA = pointerA.next;
        }
        while (pointerB != null) {
            stackB.push(pointerB.val);
            pointerB = pointerB.next;
        }

        // find the common part between A & B, then build the comment node
        ListNode intersect = null;
        while (!stackA.empty() && !stackB.empty() && stackA.peek() == stackB.peek()) {
            ListNode newHead = new ListNode(stackA.peek());
            newHead.next = intersect;
            intersect = newHead;
            stackA.pop();
            stackB.pop();
        }
        return intersect;
    }
}
```

> **Submission Result: Wrong Answer**
>
> - Input: Intersected at '10000':
>
>   - [1,3,5,7,9,...,9991,9993,9995,9997,9999,10000]
>   - [2,4,6,8,10,...,9990,9992,9994,9996,9998,10000]
> - Output: No intersection
> - Expected: Intersected at '10000'

I know that there's better algorithm to handle this test, but in this post, I just want to find out which line is wrong here.

Comment: Are you referring to this http://www.programcreek.com/2014/02/leetcode-intersection-of-two-linked-lists-java/ ?  It looks like that solution is to advance a head pointer along the longer of the two lists until the lengths are the same.  Then do a head to head comparison, advancing the head along both.  No stack needed, O(n).

Comment: Thanks @danh, I'll look at other solution at the second time. But as I said, _in this post, I just want to find out which line is wrong here._

Comment: I see, but what makes you suppose that your solution has just one erroneous line?  For example, what if your lists diverge again at the tail?  The bottom loop will fail immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Stack` data structure uses object `Integer` instead of primitive type `int`. So I need to change the comparison to

```
stackA.peek().equals(stackB.peek())
```

And the submission is accepted this time.

Now if you were interested in this algorithm test, you can find better solution in [the LeetCode forum](https://discuss.leetcode.com/topic/28067/java-solution-without-knowing-the-difference-in-len) or [Program Creek](http://www.programcreek.com/2014/02/leetcode-intersection-of-two-linked-lists-java/) provided by danh.

Comment: Alternatively you can use `Integer.intValue()` and compare with `==`.